# How do you unescape "C-like backslash escape sequence" that come from a function?

Tags: postgresql, functions, string

This will unescape the `\n\n` sequence.

```
SELECT E'\n\nFOO';
```

But if that same sequence comes from a function, what do you do.

```
CREATE FUNCTION asdf() RETURNS text
AS $$
  SELECT '\n\nFOO'::text
$$ LANGUAGE 'sql';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pg doesn't appear to expose its string parsing/lexing to SQL. It has `quote_literal` etc but doesn't seem to have the reverse. So I'm not aware of another way to do this without breaking out into a PL or writing a simple C extension.

e.g.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pyunquote(quoted text) RETURNS text AS $$
return quoted.decode("string-escape")
$$ LANGUAGE plpythonu;
```

then

```
test=# SELECT pyunquote('\n\nAAA');
 pyunquote 
-----------
          +
          +
 AAA
(1 row)
```

*but* note that this uses Python's string escape rules, not PostgreSQL's.

To get PostgreSQL's rules, you could use the following horribly insecure approach and trust whatever the function passes you:

```
DO
LANGUAGE plpgsql
$$
DECLARE
  x text;
BEGIN
  EXECUTE format('SELECT E''%s''', '\n\nFOO') INTO x;
  RAISE NOTICE 'value is "%"', x;
END;
$$;
```

[but of course someone can pass `';DROP TABLE customer;--` which won't be fun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: I'll still upvote, but I can't take myself to choosing that. =( Oh well, needed it for this, https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/175841/2639 Interestingly `pg_get_functiondef` returns the definition with the escaped new lines.

Comment: @EvanCarroll see edit

Comment: Better, move that self-destructive function to the bottom. That's a horrible idea. ;)